# Two Celery Processes Running

Tags: python, django, celery

I am debugging an issue where every scheduled task is run twice. I saw two processes named celery. Is it normal for two celery tasks to be running?

```
$ ps -ef | grep celery 

hgarg   303 32764  0 17:24 ?        00:00:00 /home/hgarg/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/hgarg_env/bin/python /data/hgarg/current/manage.py celeryd -B -s celery -E --scheduler=djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler -P eventlet -c 1000 -f /var/log/celery/celeryd.log -l INFO --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celeryd.pid --verbosity=1 --settings=settings
hgarg   307 21179  0 17:24 pts/1    00:00:00 grep celery
hgarg 32764     1  4 17:24 ?        00:00:00 /home/hgarg/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/hgarg_env/bin/python /data/hgarg/current/manage.py celeryd -B -s celery -E --scheduler=djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler -P eventlet -c 1000 -f /var/log/celery/celeryd.log -l INFO --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celeryd.pid --verbosity=1 --settings=settings
```

Comment: You've been [here](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/215), right?

Comment: Thanks, just went there. Not sure why this should start all of a sudden when it has been working for over a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two pairs of Celery processes, the older of which shouldn't have been. Killing them all and restarting celery seems to have fixed it. Without any other recent changes, unlikely that anything else could have caused it.